# (Java) Printing Tic Tac Toe Board after Initialization

Tags: java

I'm creating a simple Tic Tac Toe game. I've declared my 3 by 3 board and initialized each play area to `' '` or a space character.

However, when I try to print the board so that I get something that looks like this:

```
   1   2   3
A    |   |    
   ----------
B    |   |   
   ----------
C    |   |
```

Nothing gets printed.

Here is my TicTacToe.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           new TicTacToe();
    }
    private char[][] board;
    private char player;

    public TicTacToe() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <3; j++)
         {
           board[i][j] = ' ';
         }
    }
     player = 'X';

    System.out.println(" 1 2 3");
    System.out.println("A" + board[0][0] + "|" + board[0][1] + "|" + board[0][2]);  
    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println("B" + board[1][0] + "|" + board[1][1] + "|" + board[1][2]);  
    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println("C" + board[2][0] + "|" + board[2][1] + "|" + board[2][2]);                        
    }
```

I've read from Murach's 4th edition that when the class is executed, the constructor is executed as well so I assume that the print functions will be executed.

Question:

**How do I print my tic tac toe board like the one above to my console?**

Edit:
Thank you for the help. Turns out I had to call the constructor instead of it automatically being executed. Code above does not contain the solution.

Comment: You appear to have an empty `main` method, what's going on there?

Comment: tip: produce a minimal working example instead of posting lots of code :p (it's also a good method to solve the issue by yourself, not in this case though)

Comment: @keyser5053 Thanks for the suggestion. My 1st attempt at OOP :)

Comment: @hyngyn np, and it's a good attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in the code

```
public class TicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToe();
    }

    private char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    private char player;

    public TicTacToe() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        player = 'X';

        System.out.println(" 1 2 3");
        System.out.println("A" + board[0][0] + "|" + board[0][1] + "|"
                + board[0][2]);
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("B" + board[1][0] + "|" + board[1][1] + "|"
                + board[1][2]);
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("C" + board[2][0] + "|" + board[2][1] + "|"
                + board[2][2]);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

When a class is executed, its `main` method is executed. Your `main` method is empty, so nothing is happening. If you want to call the constructor, you have to explicitly do so.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new TicTacToe();
}
```

Comment: I get an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` pointing at where I set `board[i][j] = ' ';`

Comment: @hyngyn You never initialize your array.

Comment: @hyngyn Initialize "board", setting its size

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's printing because you're not instantiating anything inside of `main()`.  You have to use your objects inside of `main()` before anything will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have anything in your main method

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // insert code to set up your tictactoe object  here
    TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe();
}
private char[][] board;
private char player; // 'X' or 'O'

public TicTacToe() {
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <3; j++)
     {
       board[i][j] = ' ';
     }
}
 player = 'X';

System.out.println(" 1 2 3");
System.out.println("A" + board[0][0] + "|" + board[0][1] + "|" + board[0][2]);  
System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println("B" + board[1][0] + "|" + board[1][1] + "|" + board[1][2]);  
System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println("C" + board[2][0] + "|" + board[2][1] + "|" + board[2][2]);                        
}
```